# Как сделать бургер меню по диагонали?

Tags: html, сss3

Нужно сделать бургер меню как в этом примере по диагонали
https://www.schindele-handel.de/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Открываете отладчик и смотрите, как это сделано на данном сайте.

Меню самое обычное, просто с помощью `transform: translate3d(-141.5px,0,0) skewX(-20.65deg);` и абсолютного позиционирования фонового блока `<div class="sfm-sidebar-bg"></div>` кажется, что это меню по диагонали.

Такой нехитрый визуальный эффект.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если так прописать, то и пункты меню под углом становятся, а не весь блок, не могли бы вы для примера в jsfiddle накидать, а то так не совсем понятно

Comment: @GoldTrade, Вы невнимательно прочитали мой ответ и не посмотрели код в отладчике: это ФОНОВЫЙ блок, он к пунктам меню не имеет никакого отношения, он просто под них так подложен

Comment: получается нужно обернуть блок с менюшкой в фоновый блок с вот этим искажением, но тут еще остается вопрос как затемнить область справа от меню?